# regular expressions using java.util.regex API- java

Tags: java, regex

How can I create a regular expression to search strings with a given pattern? For example I want to search all strings that match pattern '*index.tx?'. Now this should find strings with values index.txt,mainindex.txt and somethingindex.txp.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("*.html");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("input.html");
```

This code is obviously not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [learn regular expression syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html). It is *not* the same as using wildcards. Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*index\\.tx.$");
```

There is a lot of information about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). You may find the program [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) useful while you are learning regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`*` matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding token, so if you want to match zero or more of any character, use `.*` instead (`.` matches any char).

Modified regex should look something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*\\.html$");
```

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `.*` matches zero or more of any char
- `\\.` matches the dot char (if not escaped it would match any char)
- `$` matches the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not work because:

1. dot `.` is a special regex character. It means *one instance of any character*.
2. `*` means *any number of occurrences of the preceding character*.

therefore, `.*` means *any number of occurrences of any character*.

so you would need something like

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\.html.*");
```

the reason for the `\\` is because we want to insert dot, although it is a special regex sign.
this means: match a string in which at first there are any number of wild characters, followed by a dot, followed by `html`, followed by anything.